# TextView and Scroll View

Tags: android

I have put textview in scrollview it's working fine.
I want to do that if user should not to scroll textview, inspite of textview should pro-grammatically scroll  to the last line.

does is possible?
How?

Comment: what do u mean.. :? i couldn't understand the line above the last line.. :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually let your scrollView to scroll to the bottom. In that way whenever that event gets triggered automatically your ScrollView will scroll and cursor will be at las line.

You can use `getScrollView().fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);` which you can actually spawn as a new thread and run.